# passing component state to redux-form onSubmit

Tags: redux-form

novice user of redux-form here. I have a signin modal that has 2 different operations: login and register. The role (stored in component state) will be `login` by default, and the user will be able to click a button to change it to `register`.

Where I'm stuck, is that I want to pass that piece of state to the `onSubmit()` function, so that I can dispatch the correct actions depending on if the user is trying to login or register.

My thinking was that I could pass down this piece of state called *signInType* as a prop to the function. Of course, it is not working as I would have expected. I can pass in a prop via the reduxForm HOC, but from that function I cannot access the component's state.

Here are the relevant parts of my component to help understand what my end goal is here:

```
const [signInType, setSignInType] = useState('login')
```

```
const onSubmit = (data, dispatch, props) => {
  console.log('props: ', props);
  if (props.signInType === 'login') {
    return (
      api.post('/Login', data)
      .then(json => {
        const response = JSON.parse(json.d)
        if (!response.userid) {
          console.error(response.message)
          dispatch(emailLoginFailure(response.message))
          return response.message
        }
        LogRocket.identify(response.userid, {
          email: data.email,
        })
        dispatch(emailLoginSuccess(response))
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
        dispatch(emailLoginFailure(err))
      })
    )
  } else if (props.signInType === 'register') {
    return (
      api.post('/RegisterByEmail', {
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
        utm_source: "Development",
        utm_medium: "email",
        utm_campaign: "Campaign Test",
        utm_term: "N/A",
        utm_content: "123",
        utm_date: "2019-02-11 12:25:36"
      })
      .then(json => {
        const response = JSON.parse(json.d)
        if (!response.userid) {
          console.error(response.message)
          dispatch(emailRegisterFailure(response.message))
          return response.message
        }
        // LogRocket.identify(response.userid, {
        //   email: data.email,
        // })
        dispatch(emailRegisterSuccess(response))
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error("Unable to register email:", err)
      })
    )
  } else {
    console.error("error: No signin type?")
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such login/register flow I prefer handling it with different components, in order to respect and follow SRP.

Also, I'm not sure how do you organize your components, but here's how I deal with such a scenario:

**Your Modal:**

* *It will be responsible only for rendering Login or Register forms.*

```js
const Modal = () => {
  const [signInType, ] = useState('login')

  const isLogin = signInType === 'login' 

  return <>
    { isLogin ? <LoginForm /> : <RegisterForm /> }

    <button onClick={() => setSignInType(isLogin ? 'register' : 'login')}>
      { isLogin ? 'Sign up' : 'Sign in' }
    </button>
  </>
}
```

**LoginForm:**

* *Now you can pass your login action to `onSubmit` prop*. `Login` will be your presentation component, while `LoginForm` decorates `Login` with `reduxForm` HOC.

```js
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'login',
  onSubmit: data => {}
})(Login)
```

**RegisterForm:**

* *Here we follow the same idea as `LoginForm`.*

```js
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'register',
  onSubmit: data => {}
})(Register)
```